# BSDA package for Z.Test

Tags: r, statistics

Currently, I am using the r 4.0.5 version, and while doing z test analysis the needed package BSDA is not present. Although I tried to install it from different sources but could not succeed. Anyone can come up with the idea, so I can proceed with the final task.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error message are you getting when running `install.packages("BSDA")`? Are you able to update your version of R?

Comment: The error is object BSDA not found, and yes I tried to upgrade and downgrade the existing r version, however, the issue has not been resolved...

Comment: currently, I am using the 4.0.5 r version.

Comment: Make sure to include quotes around BSDA in the line `install.packages("BSDA")` otherwise R thinks you're referring to an object in the environment by that name. And I would suggest updating R to the latest version - 4.2.1